# ASP.NET MVC add a query string to a route when the page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a MVC 5 web site search criteria , when my page first loads, the URL looks like this: http://myapp.com.

However, I'd like it to look like this: http://myapp.com?HotelID=12&Rate='abc'&Culture='En' and so on (?HotelID=12&Rate='abc'&Culture='En'  is the important part).

also i have class session-helper has the default values that i want to put it inside query string on page load i don't know if that possible .

this is the session helper-class :

```
 public  class SessionHelper
{
    public SessionHelper()
    {
        // ------ Set default values here 
        Rate = "";
        HotelID = 0;
        CSS_FileName = "default.css";
        Culture = "En";                        
        Checkin = DateTime.Today.Date;
        Checkout = DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(1);
        //Maximum numbers
        MaximumNumberOfRooms = 4;
        MaximumNumberOfAdultsPerRoom = 4;
        MaximumNumberOfChildrenPerRoom = 3;
        MaximumDaysAheadBookable = 450;
        MaximumDaysBetweenCheckinCheckout = 31;

        // You don't need to create an instance on the first page, this will be created on the class constuctor
        IBE_DLL_Instance = new RHN_IBE.IBE();
    }

    #region String properties
    public  string Rate
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["Rate"] as string; }

        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["Rate"] = value; }
    }

    public string CSS_FileName
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["CSS_FileName"] as string; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["CSS_FileName"] = value; }
    }
    public string Culture
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["Culture"] as string; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["Culture"] = value; }
    }


    #endregion

    #region Integer properties
    public int HotelID
    {
        get { return (int)(HttpContext.Current.Session["HotelID"]); }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["HotelID"] = value; }
    }

    public int SearchCriteria_NumberOfAdultsPerRoom
    {
        get { return (int)(HttpContext.Current.Session["SearchCriteria_NumberOfAdultsPerRoom"]); }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["SearchCriteria_NumberOfAdultsPerRoom"] = value; }
    }
    public int SearchCriteria_NumberOfChildrenPerRoom
    {
        get { return (int)(HttpContext.Current.Session["SearchCriteria_NumberOfChildrenPerRoom"]); }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["SearchCriteria_NumberOfChildrenPerRoom"] = value; }
    }
    public int SearchCriteria_NumberOfRooms
    {
        get { return (int)(HttpContext.Current.Session["SearchCriteria_NumberOfRooms"]); }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["SearchCriteria_NumberOfRooms"] = value; }
    }

    //Maximum numbers defaulot value 
    public int MaximumNumberOfRooms
    {
        get { return (int)(HttpContext.Current.Session["MaximumNumberOfRooms"]); }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["MaximumNumberOfRooms"] = value; }
    }

    public int MaximumNumberOfAdultsPerRoom
    {
        get { return (int)(HttpContext.Current.Session["MaximumNumberOfAdultsPerRoom"]); }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["MaximumNumberOfAdultsPerRoom"] = value; }
    }

    public int MaximumNumberOfChildrenPerRoom
    {
        get { return (int)(HttpContext.Current.Session["MaximumNumberOfChildrenPerRoom"]); }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["MaximumNumberOfChildrenPerRoom"] = value; }
    }

    public int MaximumDaysAheadBookable
    {
        get { return (int)(HttpContext.Current.Session["MaximumDaysAheadBookable"]); }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["MaximumDaysAheadBookable"] = value; }
    }

    public int MaximumDaysBetweenCheckinCheckout
    {
        get { return (int)(HttpContext.Current.Session["MaximumDaysBetweenCheckinCheckout"]); }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["MaximumDaysBetweenCheckinCheckout"] = value; }
    }



    #endregion

    #region Date properties
    public DateTime Checkin
    {
        get { return (DateTime)(HttpContext.Current.Session["Checkin"]); }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["Checkin"] = value; }
    }

    public DateTime Checkout
    {
        get { return (DateTime)(HttpContext.Current.Session["Checkout"]); }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["Checkout"] = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region DLL Instance 
    public RHN_IBE.IBE IBE_DLL_Instance
    {
        get { return (RHN_IBE.IBE)(HttpContext.Current.Session["IBE_DLL_Instance"]); }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["IBE_DLL_Instance"] = value; }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

This is my controller i initialize session-helper class as global variable to call it once the page load and sit the default values on page-load

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    SessionHelper mysession = new SessionHelper();
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index_Get()
    {
        //checkURL();                        

        pageload();

        return View(mysession);            
    }
 }
```

And this is my form :

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
                  {
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                            <p class="font">@Resource.criteria_Arrival</p>
                            <input class="calendarr font" name="Arrival" readonly type="text" id="Arrival" onchange="changedDate()">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                            <p class="font">@Resource.criteria_Departure</p>
                            <input class="calendarr font" name="Departure" readonly type="text" id="Departure">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 font">
                            <p>@Resource.criteria_Rooms</p>                            
                            <select id="Rooms" name="Rooms" class="dropdown">
                                @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.MaximumNumberOfRooms; i++)
                                {                                   
                                   <option value="@i">@i</option>                                   
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix visible-md-block">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 font">
                            <p>@Resource.criteria_Persons</p>
                            <select id="Persons" name="Persons" class="dropdown">
                                @for (int j = 1; j <= Model.MaximumNumberOfAdultsPerRoom; j++)
                                {                                                                       
                                <option value="@j">@j</option>                                   
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-1 font">
                            <p>@Resource.criteria_Children</p>
                            <select id="Childrens" name="Childrens" class="dropdown">
                                @for (int c = 1; c <= Model.MaximumNumberOfChildrenPerRoom; c++)
                                {                                   
                                <option value="@c">@c</option>                                    
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 font">
                            <br />
                            <input type="submit" class="btns" value=@Resource.criteria_btn_Search /><br />
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="Login" style="font-size: x-small; color: #337ab7; float: right; position: relative; left: -14px; top: 10px;">@Resource.criteria_link_AlreadyamemberLogin</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                  }
```

I tried several ways but not worked with me any advice . thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would need a session if you want to store the information in the url. In my answer I am not using the session, but instead focus on the url.

First of all you can use an object to automatically bind the parameters:

```
//using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class SessionParameters
{
    [Required]
    public string Rate { get; set; } = "";
    [Required]
    public string Culture { get; set; } = "En";
    [Required]
    public int HotelID { get; set; } = 0;
    public int SearchCriteria_NumberOfAdultsPerRoom { get; set; }
    public int SearchCriteria_NumberOfChildrenPerRoom { get; set; }
    public int SearchCriteria_NumberOfRooms { get; set; }
    public int MaximumNumberOfRooms { get; set; } = 4;
    public int MaximumNumberOfAdultsPerRoom { get; set; } = 4;
    public int MaximumNumberOfChildrenPerRoom { get; set; } = 3;
    public int MaximumDaysAheadBookable { get; set; } = 450;
    public int MaximumDaysBetweenCheckinCheckout { get; set; } = 31;
    // You may want to use a specific format for dates.
    public DateTime Checkin { get; set; } = DateTime.Today.Date;
    public DateTime Checkout { get; set; } = DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(1);
}
```

Notice the Required fields. In your controller add the class as parameter:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    SessionHelper mysession = new SessionHelper();

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index_Get(SessionParameters pars)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", routeValues: new SessionParameters());

        //checkURL();                        

        pageload();

        return View(pars);            
    }
 }
```

How this works: pars will be initialized as a new SessionParameters object (meaning that the default values are set!) where present url parameters are overwritten with the actual value.

We cannot tell whether this is a first entry, but we can test the ModelState. If invalid, we need to set the default values.

What will work in this case, is the Rate field. Rate is required but has a default value of "". This will cause ModelState to be invalid if Rate is omitted.

So in case you hit http://myapp.com, pars is automatically mapped as a new SessionParameters object. And because Rate == "" ModelState wil not be valid. Now we can redirect to the same action with the new SessionParameters (containing the default values) which are now shown as parameters in the url.

It may not be exactly what you are looking for, but I hope this gives you an idea on how you may solve this issue.

Comment: I use `mysession` as model on view, i want to pass `mysession` to view and `SessionParameters` at the same time ? , mysession  this  is a global variable an instance of the `SessionHelper` class  , i use this instance  while making the design of the page . when i test your code now i have this error _The page isn’t redirecting properly_

Comment: I didn't notice you are using mvc4. Did you try my code without mysession (and setting the viewmodel in the view to SessionParameters)? If so, then this may not work because you are using mvc4. I know this code works in mvc5. Though I think this should work in mvc4 as well.

Comment: As a sidenote. I don't think mysession is suitable as ViewModel. I use ViewModels for the model data only. This ViewModel is a simple DTO (like the example). If I want additional information I can use ViewBag. Like lookup data for dropdownlist, page title, etc. I never use session information because I store the information in the url or I retrieve the information from the database (easy for authenticated users).

Comment: I am using mvc 5.2 VS_2017 and still the code did not work

Comment: Can you be more specific? Assuming you have the code in  my example. If you set a breakpoint on 'if (!ModelState.IsValid)'. Does pars have a value? If you skip pageload and move to 'return View(pars)', what happens? Make sure that the view uses SessionParameters. Comment code in the view that can't be mapped to SessionParameters.

Comment: I set a breakpoint on 'if (!ModelState.IsValid)' pars have a value ,if i skip pageload and move to 'return View(pars)' he dose not move to 'return View(pars)' he just move to (!ModelState.IsValid)' and retrun `RedirectToAction("Index", routeValues: new SessionParameters());` also the view used SessionParameters as a  model but still have the same problem , the problem is i get the `SessionParameters` on the url as a query string but i don't have the design or the search criteria gives me this message   **The page isn’t redirecting properly**

Comment: I think the redirect works, but you are rerouted to the method again. You move to return View(pars) and then re-enter the method. I think there is something in your routing what causes the redirect. Perhaps you'll need to set some session variable that is now null.

Comment: Now,when i set breakpoint on ` if (!ModelState.IsValid)`  is = false,  when i skip pageload and move to 'return View(pars)'  and the view  uses SessionParameters i see the search criteria but i don't have the query string parameters on the top of URL